# Nginx ingress controller configuration (gke)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I've done the installation of `Nginx Ingress Controller` by using this guide (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) in 2 steps:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

Then it created for me 2 entities :

[image]

first entity is called `ingress-nginx` in `service & ingress` section and the second one:

[image]

inside workloads section called `nginx-ingress-controller`. Next step of my configuration process was creating service with Ingress type:

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-ingress-controller"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my static ip
 name: booknotes-ingress 
 namespace: 'default'  
spec:
 rules:
 - host: www.domain.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /*
       backend:
         serviceName: booknotes-service
         servicePort: 80
```

Then I've exposed `booknotes-service` from my `booknotes` (Depoloyment) with `Custer IP` type . But when I go to www.domain.com it is in a pending state . What I've done wrong ? And I don't really understand well all the flow from the request to my pod in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` is set correctly?  If not specified as an arg in the deployment/pod, it's just `nginx` by default.

Comment: I thought it should be the name of my nginx ingress controller, I've changed it , but it is the same . I've also tried to run the same by passing all steps from this tutorial

https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/872?catalog_rank=%7B%22rank%22%3A1%2C%22num_filters%22%3A0%2C%22has_search%22%3Atrue%7D&parent=catalog&search_id=3689651

But result is the same

Comment: the annotation it should be as this {kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"} and what do you mean by "pending" is the external IP is in pending state for the LoadBalancer?

Comment: it loads some time and then I see (This site can’t be reached)

Answer (score 1):

Have you binded the external ip address of your ingress controller to your dns? Can you resolve the dns? Try `nslookup www.domain.com` and check if the ip address is the one of your ingress controller.

Once you resolve the problem with the dns you may get either a 404 or a 502 as response. Which means you are resolving but not passing traffic to the service. Update your question with that and we can continue.

Pd.- Remove the `/*` in the path definition of the ingress resource. Just `/`